# Add UIView rounding logic inside UIView class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom UIView and I add it to my ViewController like this:

```
let myCustomView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyCustomView", owner: nil, options: nil) as! MyCustomView
myCustomView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
myCustomView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

I round the corners of the view. But I am wondering, is there a way to move this logic of rounding the corners inside the MyCustomView class?

Comment: where are your calling this ..

Comment: Hey @BlueBoy, welcome to StackOverflow. If you have a moment to mark one of the answers as accepted, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you use IB, you may find it more convenient to make an extension of `UIView`

```
extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
        get {
            if let color = layer.borderColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor:color)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            clipsToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can set those values from Attributes inspector.

[image]

Comment: Awesome solution :)

Comment: I really can't see why this is considered a good solution. You're exposing these properties to every single UIView class whereas the question was asking about one specific subclass. I would imagine this would slow down the loading of a storyboard considerably too.

Comment: @Leon "considerably" sounds a bit heavy. I've stated that "if you use IB" and "for convenience". I also agree with the overhead pointed out.

Comment: Perhaps, although it looks like the UIView doesn't render in the storyboard anyway so there's no real impact. However, this was not the main issue raised.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - If you're loading a nib with a custom view, that nib is very likely referring to another class. If that's the case, you can move the logic inside the class itself.

[image: A screenshot illustrating Xcode's Interface Builder]

That said, I really like [Lawliet's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44897000/224988) of making a UIView extension with `IBInspectable` properties. The downside to that approach is that every single view now has these properties, which creates a certain overhead and potential for clashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your UIView subclass:

```
class RoundedView: UIView {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

Also if you want to pass a custom value instead of '10' in the cornerRadius property, you can try to implement a convenience init by looking here:

[Override Init method of UIView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496962/override-init-method-of-uiview-in-swift)

Comment: this is what i am looking for but getting `fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented` when I run it

Comment: try to add this in init coder function

super.init(coder: aDecoder)

Comment: that stops the crash, but has no effect.

Comment: Oh...my bad. You are loading the view from a nib file. That will cause init(coder:) to be called instead of init(frame:). So you need those 2 lines for setting the layer property in init(coder:) function as well. I have updated my answer.