# Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer Error

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am developing a SpriteKit game which uses a joystick. I have created a joystick SKNode Class.

The code for the class:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Joystick: SKNode {
    var joystickPad: SKShapeNode!
    var joystickStick: SKShapeNode!

    var colour: UIColor!

    init(colour: UIColor) {
        //constructor method
        self.colour = colour;
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // lots of other code unrelated to the error
}
```

I got the following error when I run my code:

> Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer

Can anyone please explain the error and tell me any solutions, I don't get why I'm getting that error, as I thought my class was just a class not a superclass.

Any Help would be much appreciated.

**Additional Info:**

I'm using:

- Swift 4
- Spritekit
- Xcode 9.2
- iPhone 6s Running the latest public release iOS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Super.init isn't called before returning from initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30877156/1187415)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your class inherited from `SKNode`.

Subclasses should call superclass init if they declares new designated initializer. You can find more info about initialization [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID216]).

You can just add `super.init()` call in your `init` to fix the error.

```
init(colour: UIColor) {
    //constructor method
    self.colour = colour;
    super.init()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> as I thought my class was just a class not a superclass

Your class is a *subclass*. Therefore you must call the superclass's designated initializer in your initializer:

```
init(colour: UIColor) {
    self.colour = colour
    super.init()
}
```

Comment: Here's my summary of the rules: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_subclass_initializers